# Суммирование и группировка одинаковых элементов в List

Tags: c#, list, linq

В чем суть. Нужно создать отчет показывающий сколько продавали товаров за промежуток времени. Есть вот такой лист:

```
SearchList = context.Продажа.ToList();
SearchList = SearchList.Where(x => x.Дата_продажи >= DPFirstDate.SelectedDate && x.Дата_продажи <= DPSecondDate.SelectedDate).ToList();
```

Нужно представить список таким образом, чтобы количество проданных товаров в списке суммировалось, то-есть такой список:

```
Компьютерная мышь - 1 
Коврик - 4
Коврик - 1
Компьютерная мышь - 3
```

Представлялся таким образом :

```
Коврик - 5    
Компьютерная мышь - 4
```

Пробовал уже разные способы, но так ничего и не получилось.
Пытаюсь пока так, но подчеркивается Номенклатура.Наименование

```
var result = SearchList
.GroupBy(x => x.Номенклатура.Наименование)
.Select(x => new Продажа() { Номенклатура.Наименование = x.Key, Количество = x.Sum(z => z.Количество) })
.ToList();
```

Если что, то название товара я получаю через - Номенклатура.Наименование, а количество находится в таблице Продажа, на которой лист, собственно, и основан.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `Пробовал уже разные способы, но так ничего и не получилось` - какие? Где они? Вот просто подумайте логически, у вас есть список объектов, где объекты могут иметь одинаковые названия, но разные значения, что надо сделать, чтоб эти "одинаковые названия" объединить? Наверно сгруппировать, верно (`GrouBy()`)? Ок, сгруппировали, дальше какие действия? Наверно надо привести их к нужному виду (`Select`), у нужного вида суммируем сразу значения (`Sum`). Вот, собственно, и вся логика, которая вроде очень простая. в чем тогда у вас проблемы?

Comment: Именно с этим Select я разобраться и не могу

Comment: `с этим Select я разобраться и не могу` - Ну смотрите, `Select` это метод, который через лямбду получает объект коллекции (`x=>` где x - это объект), а сам через `return` должен вернуть что угодно обратно (`x=> {return "Привет мир!";} ` (сокращенно `x=> "Привет мир!"`)). Вернуть вы можете хоть отдельно созданный для этого класс, хоть анонимные типы (`new {SomeValue = 1, Value = true}`), хоть кортежи `(Item: 1, Value: true)`, ну вот с этим и играйтесь, например `Select(x=>new {Item = x, Sum = x.Sum(s => s.Value)} )`.

Comment: что за класс Продажа? Добавь его определдение

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете использовать [Object Initializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer) чтобы иницализировать свойства дочерних объектов.

Если класс Продажа создает класс Номенклатура в конструкторе, вы можете передать Наименование через параметр:

```cs
new Продажа(x.Key) { Количество = x.Sum(z => z.Количество) }
```

Если класс Продажа не создает Номенклатуру, тогда просто добавите вложенный Object Initializer:

```cs
new Продажа() { Номенклатура = new Номенклатура() { Наименование = x.Key }, Количество = x.Sum(z => z.Количество) }
```